# Remover tags HTML com regexp na query

Tags: mysql, query, regex

Estou tentando fazer uma query no MySQL 5.7 usando regexp para ignorar tags HTML, até o momento tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT * FROM question WHERE question.enunciation REGEXP '[^<|</]center[^\>]' = true
```

Considerando que tenho esses dados no BD:

```
ID  ENUNCIATION
1   <center>Random question</center>
2   center Text
3   Text center
4   <center>Random center question</center>
5   <p>Random question</p> <strong>center</strong>
```

Quando eu executo essa query, esperava que retornasse esses dados:

```
ID  ENUNCIATION
2   center Text
3   Text center
4   <center>Random center question</center>
5   <p>Random question</p> <strong>center</strong>
```

Porém está retornando somente o seguinte dado:

```
ID  ENUNCIATION
4   <center>Random center question</center>
5   <p>Random question</p> <strong>center</strong>
```

Estou errando no regexp? Se sim, como consigo resolver?

Gostaria de resolver isso sem ter que criar uma função no MySql.

Uma possível solução que tive até o momento foi salvar as informações dessa coluna em outra retirando as tags HTML e fazer o filtro nessa nova coluna.

Basicamente desejo fazer um filtro como se fosse um LIKE mas que ignorasse o valor pesquisado sempre que estivesse entre tags e se existir esse valor sem ser tag deve trazer no resultado

Comment: Ignorar "tags" ou a tag específica "<center>"?

Comment: seria ignorar tags mesmo, o center foi um exemplo, basicamente meu problema é o seguinte:
Quando um usuário pesquisar um termo no enuncioado de questões, eu tenho que ignorar se esse termo estiver dentro de tags, por que ele pode ser uma tag HTML e não faria sentido eu trazer para ele uma questão sem o termo que ele pesquisou.

Comment: Tente: `'<(/)?.{1,}>' = false`

Comment: @Sam tentei da seguinte forma: 

SELECT * FROM question WHERE question.enunciation REGEXP '<(/)?.{1,}>' = false and question.enunciation like '%center%'

Porém se o valor for:

1   <center>Random center question</center>

Ele não vem, precisaria que no caso o filtro só ignorasse o que tiver dentro da tag mesmo, mas se tiver o valor sem ser tag, deve trazer, muito obrigado por tentar me ajudar

Comment: @FabioBueno Seria interessante você **[edit]** a pergunta e colocar esses exemplos lá também. Por exemplo, se for `abc <center> texto</center>`, você quer que retorne `abc`? (para mim não ficou muito claro). Os textos sempre tem apenas uma tag, ou podem ter tags dentro de outras (e nesse caso, ignora tudo dentro dessas tags?). Pode ter casos de tags mal formadas? E tags que não tem fechamento, como `<br>`, `<img>`, etc, tem que ser retiradas também? Enfim, dependendo do que for, é mais fácil tratar isso fora do SQL, ainda mais que regex no MySQL é meio limitado...

Comment: @hkotsubo muito obrigado pela dica, vou tentar arrumar, mas uma solução que tive até o momento é salvar em uma coluna nova o ENUNCIATION sem as tags htmls que pode ter nele e fazer o filtro nessa coluna.

Comment: Depois da edição, não entendi porque a linha 4 é retornada e a linha 1 não, pois ambas tem o texto todo dentro da tag. E a linha 5 está com tags mal formadas, é isso mesmo? A tag só pode ser `center` ou é qualquer tag?

Comment: A diferença é que na linha 1 só existe o termo center como tag, e na linha 4 o termo center existe sem ser uma tag, logo eu quero trazer esse valor, por que existe o termo pesquisado.
Pode ser qualquer tag e eu já arrumei, estava errado a tag, obrigado.

Comment: Mas o item 4 possui também todo o texto dentro da tag `center`. Mesmo assim deve ser retornado, só porque também tem o nome da tag no meio do texto?

Comment: Sim, eu preciso que ignore as tags, mas se tiver o valor sem ser tag o mesmo deve retornar

Comment: Nesse caso eu realmente recomendo que faça fora do SQL, por 2 motivos: 1- processar HTML desta maneira é mais fácil usando libs específicas (parsers ou bibliotecas dedicadas, etc). 2- até é possível [fazer uma regex](https://regex101.com/r/sV5uuM/1/) que detecte esses casos (e funciona para os casos mais simples), mas tem que usar alguns recursos que o MySQL não suporta (a menos que vc instale [uma lib](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme) para isso). Mas acho que não vale a pena, acho mais fácil processar o HTML fora do banco mesmo...

Comment: @hkotsubo Muito obrigado pela ajuda, acho que essa seria realmente a melhor solução

Comment: Acho que você poderia usar um regex_replace, com a expressão <.*> por vazio. Dessa forma você vai conseguir eliminar tudo que estiver entre < e >.